# Ошибка при загрузке изображения с помощью vova07\imperavi

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, yii

Хочу загрузить изображение на сервер с помощью расширения `vova07\imperavi\Widget`, но при загрузке происходить ошибка `ERROR_DURING_UPLOAD_PROCESS`
Код
`_form.php`

```
    <?php use vova07\imperavi\Widget; ?>
   <?= $form->field($model, 'content_ru')->widget(Widget::className(), [
        'settings' => [
            'lang' => 'ru',
            'minHeight' => 200,
            'imageUpload' => Url::to(['app-admin/image-upload']),
            'imageManagerJson' => Url::to(['app-admin/images-get']),
            'fileUpload' => Url::to(['app-admin/file-upload']),
            'fileManagerJson' => Url::to(['app-admin/files-get']),
            'plugins' => [
                'clips',
                'fullscreen',
                'imagemanager' => 'vova07\imperavi\bundles\ImageManagerAsset',
                'filemanager' => 'vova07\imperavi\bundles\FileManagerAsset',
            ],
            'imageDeleteCallback' => new \yii\web\JsExpression(
                'function(url) {deleteimg(url);}'
            ),
            'clips' => [
                ['red', '<span class="label-red">red</span>'],
                ['green', '<span class="label-green">green</span>'],
                ['blue', '<span class="label-blue">blue</span>'],
            ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

`app\modules\admin\AppAdminController`

```
<?php
namespace app\modules\admin\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\HttpException;


class AppAdminController extends Controller
{
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'images-get' => [
                'class' => 'vova07\imperavi\actions\GetImagesAction',
                'url' => '/upload/images/', // Directory URL address, where files are stored.
                //'path' => '@webroot/upload/images/', // Or absolute path to directory where files are stored.
                //'options' => ['only' => ['*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.png', '*.gif', '*.ico']], // These options are by default.
            ],
            'images-upload' => [
                'class' => 'vova07\imperavi\actions\UploadFileAction',
                'url' => '/images/', // Directory URL address, where files are stored.
                'path' => Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/upload/image', // Or absolute path to directory where files are stored.
            ],
            'files-get' => [
                'class' => 'vova07\imperavi\actions\GetFilesAction',
                'url' => '/files/', // Directory URL address, where files are stored.
                'path' => Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/upload', // Or absolute path to directory where files are stored.
                'options' => ['only' => ['*.txt', '*.doc', '*.pdf']], // These options are by default.
            ],
            'file-upload' => [
                'class' => 'vova07\imperavi\actions\UploadFileAction',
                'url' => '/upload/', // Directory URL address, where files are stored.
                'path' => Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/upload', // Or absolute path to directory where files are stored.
                'uploadOnlyImage' => false, // For any kind of files uploading.
            ],
            'file-delete' => [
                'class' => 'vova07\imperavi\actions\DeleteFileAction',
                'url' => '/upload/', // Directory URL address, where files are stored.
                'path' => Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/upload', // Or absolute path to directory where files are stored.
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

В консоле получаю такую ошибку
`GET http://univer.lc/assets/781f6d28/plugins/vova07/imperavi/bundles/ImageManagerAsset/vova07/imperavi/bundles/ImageManagerAsset.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
update.html?id=10:917`

`GET http://univer.lc/assets/781f6d28/plugins/vova07/imperavi/bundles/FileManagerAsset/vova07/imperavi/bundles/FileManagerAsset.js`

Comment: Как решили проблему? У меня такая же ошибка, вернее, изображение грузится, но ошибка в консоли 404, как у Вас.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по пути `http://univer.lc/assets/781f6d28/plugins/vova07/imperavi/bundles/ImageManagerAsset/vova07/imperavi/bundles/ImageManagerAsset.js` сдается мне, что ошибка в настройке `'imagemanager' => 'vova07\imperavi\bundles\ImageManagerAsset',` и `filemanager`.